# Simple SELECT queries between 2 databases are not returning any result - keep showing "Executing query"

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have two not very complex SELECT queries that are not returning any output when i run in SSMS. When I run both of these queries separately, **i just see "Executing query" and it stays like that for a really long time.**

**[database1].[dbo].[customer]** is where all customer data is stored

**[database2].[mail].[emailsent]** is where email sent log is stored, basically which customer received which email. In this table, row only exists when an email was sent to a customer. If it was not sent then there shouldn't be any row.

**What i am trying to do -** I am trying to get all customer count (& customer keys as well) for all customers who did not receive specific emailids so i think i will need have to 2 conditions in where clause since these customers may exists with other emailids or they may not exists at all in the emailsent table.

**here is my query 1:**

```
-- query1 to get customer count
SELECT count(DISTINCT [customerkey]) AS My_Count

  FROM [database1].[dbo].[customer]  
  WHERE 
  [signupdate] BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-05-05' AND [type] = 1
  AND
  (

  ([accountid] NOT IN (select distinct [accountid] from [database2].[mail].[emailsent]))

 OR
 (
 [accountid] NOT IN (select distinct [accountid] from [database2].[mail].[emailsent] where [id] IN (
'10',
'11',
'12',
'13',
'14',
'15',
'16') )
)
)
```

**here is my query 2**

```
-- query2 to get all customers
SELECT DISTINCT [customerkey]

  FROM [database1].[dbo].[customer]  
  WHERE 
  [signupdate] BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-05-05' AND [type] = 1
  AND
  (

  ([accountid] NOT IN (select distinct [accountid] from [database2].[mail].[emailsent]))

 OR
 (
 [accountid] NOT IN (select distinct [accountid] from [database2].[mail].[emailsent] where [id] IN (
'10',
'11',
'12',
'13',
'14',
'15',
'16') )
)
)
```

Comment: Likely you face a performance issue. Describe size of data, any keys/indexes, and [execution plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-2017). For `IN` subqueries, `distinct` is redundant. Also, your `OR` conditions for `[accountid] NOT IN` overlap with each other where second is entirely redundant. Plus it appears you are querying across databases.

Answer (score 0):

If your databases are on Linked Servers then this might help:

```
SELECT cust.[customerkey], COUNT(cust.[customerkey])
FROM [database1].[dbo].[customer] cust
LEFT JOIN  [database2].[mail].[emailsent] eml ON eml.[accountid] = cust.[accountid]
WHERE eml.[accountid] IS NULL
Group By cust.[customerkey]
```

Comment: WHERE eml.[accountid] IS NULL means it will check only for customer whose record does not exist in the emailsent table? how we will make sure we are honoring the customer who received other emails other than specific IDs - please correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: To give you an example...if you are a contact and received email A, B & C from us...Now your record will exists in emailsent table. If I have a contact and I never received any email then my record won't exists in emailsent table. Now, if i want to count contacts who did not receive email X, Y & Z...I will have to contact myself, who did not receive any email+ you, who received other email (anything other than X, Y & Z). This is what i am trying to do.

Comment: Then you could do ```WHERE (eml.[accountid] IS NULL) OR (eml.[id] IN ('10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16'))```

Comment: quick question - why we are doing (eml.[id] IN ('10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16'))...and we are not doing NOT IN...shouldn't we be checking for all customers who received other emails except these specific IDs?...doing IN..will give us people who received these specific emails..no?

Comment: Sorry then change it to NOT IN

Comment: Is this correct?  `SELECT count(DISTINCT [customerkey]) AS My_Count
FROM [database1].[dbo].[customer] c LEFT JOIN [database2].[mail].[emailsent] e ON c.accountid = e.accountid AND e.id IN ('10','11','12','13','14','15','16')
WHERE c.signupdate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-05-05' AND c.type = 1
AND
e.id IS NULL `